# R regex to remove anything after second occurance of / in data frame column

Tags: regex, r

I have data stored in a `dataframe` column that looks like this:

```
/travel
/food and drink/restaurants
/food and drink
/sports/outdoors/climbing

/news
/family
```

Each row has some number of "/" but they always start with a "/".  Some lines are also blank.  I just need to convert this data to only include the text after the first "/" but before the second "/".  I also want to capitalize the first letter of each word of the result.  So I'd hope the result to look like this:

```
Travel
Food And Drink
Food And Drink
Sports

News
Family
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with R, so it may be totally inappropriate for me to respond (still sorta new here) but many languages have some analog of Split() to break strings to arrays on a delimiter.  In VB it would be Split(RowValue,"/")(1) to select the 2nd element (the first being blank because the string starts with a delimiter).  Wrapping that in a proper case function should return the output you specified.

Comment: @Snachmo Yeah, it works (Eugene's answer) and is fair on a regex question like this to comment about approaches that can be expected to work on most platforms, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x <- c('/travel',
       '/food and drink/restaurants',
       '/food and drink',
       '/sports/outdoors/climbing',
       '/news',
       '/family')
```

Upcase every word

```
gsub('(?<=\\b)([a-z])', '\\U\\1', x, perl =  TRUE)

# [1] "/Travel"                     "/Food And Drink/Restaurants" "/Food And Drink"            
# [4] "/Sports/Outdoors/Climbing"   "/News"                       "/Family"
```

Extract the first `/..` group

```
gsub('^/([^/]+)|.', '\\1', x)

# [1] "travel"         "food and drink" "food and drink" "sports"         "news"          
# [6] "family"
```

Combine the two

```
gsub('(?<=\\b)([a-z])', '\\U\\1', gsub('^/([^/]+)|.', '\\1', x), perl =  TRUE)

# [1] "Travel"         "Food And Drink" "Food And Drink" "Sports"         "News"          
# [6] "Family"
```

If you don't care about the "and" being uppercase, you can use the second `gsub` and `tools::toTitleCase`

```
tools::toTitleCase(gsub('^/([^/]+)|.', '\\1', x))

# [1] "Travel"         "Food and Drink" "Food and Drink" "Sports"         "News"          
# [6] "Family"
```

Comment: great answer @rawr! Could you please explain the regexp syntax for extracting the text between `/`s?

Comment: @sebpardo `^/` says to match `/` at the beginning of the line, `(...)` sends `...` to the first capture group which we can reference with `\\1`, the `...` in this example is a class of characters defined by `[...]` including anything except `/` which is expressed by `^/`. so this will match starting from the beginning of the line a `/` followed by (and captured) anything except `/` one or more times (the `+` means one or more). or we match any character `|.` but don't capture this second part is a nice trick to get rid of everything except the capture group in a `gsub` call. I'll add to my ans

Answer (score 1):

```
require(magrittr)

txt <- c("/travel", "/food and drink/restaurants", "/food and drink", "/sports/outdoors/climbing", "", "/news", "/family")

strsplit(txt, "/") %>% sapply( '[', 2 )  #per Frank's suggestion

##  [1] "travel"         "food and drink" "food and drink" "sports"        
##  [5] NA               "news"           "family"
```

Comment: Sorry, force of habit when using `%>%`

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice it the first time. Btw, `txt %>% strsplit("/") %>% sapply(\`[\`, 2)` works. Usually folks use library(magrittr) if only the pipe is needed.

Comment: That is fantastic! Had no idea!

Answer (score 0):

A quick way would be the following: I'm assuming that there only words characters `\w` and white spaces `\s` in the part you want to collect.

```
char<- c("/travel","/food and drink/restaurants","/food and drink","/sports/outdoors/climbing","","/news","/family")

match <- regexpr("[\\w\\s]+",char,perl=TRUE)
regmatches(char,match)

## regmatches(char,match)
## [1] "travel"         "food and drink" "food and drink" "sports"        
## [5] "news"           "family"
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install the `stringi` package (and you should probably have it anyway :) but the following should do the trick

```
stringi::stri_trans_totitle( gsub("/([^/]+)", "\\1", data))
```

The `gsub` simply picks out the text after the first `/` up until either the second `/` or the end of the string. `stringi::stri_trans_totitle` then does the case conversion for you.

```
> s <-c("/food and drink/restaurants", "/beer and wine", "", "/news")
> stringi::stri_trans_totitle( gsub("/([^/]+)", "\\1", s))
[1] "Food And Drinkrestaurants" "Beer And Wine"            
[3] ""                          "News"
```